# Compute Correlation between two binary variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

> $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two binary stochastic variables with simultaneous probabilitydistribution:
>
> $$
> \begin{matrix}
> &X_2=0&X_2=1\\
> X_1=0&0.30&0.17\\
> X_1=1&0.08&0.45
> \end{matrix}
> $$

I want to calculate the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$.

```
Correlation[{{0.30, 0.17}, {0.08, 0.45}}]
```

The output I get is `{{1,-1},{-1,1}}`

The solution I seek is: `0.05011`

It should be pretty simple, but I have no idea where I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set this up in symbolic form as a bivariate distribution with pmf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

Then, using the mathStatica add-on to *Mathematica*, the correlation you seek is:

```
Corr[{x, y}, f]
```

> $\frac{607}{\sqrt{1467199}}$

Note that this is slightly different to the solution you posted,as the numerical value is:  0.501123... (not 0.0501).

You can make *Mma* do this operation too, by itself, as per:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f, {x, 0, 1, 1}, {y, 0, 1, 1}]
```

where `f` is the piecewise function above, and then evaluate:

```
Correlation[dist]
```

---

The problem with your use of  `Correlation[{{0.30, 0.17}, {0.08, 0.45}}]` is this ...  You could use `Correlation[xdata, ydata]` to find the *sample* correlation between `xdata` and `ydata` ... but (a) you are not seeking a sample correlation ... you are seeking the *population* correlation, and (b) `{{0.30, 0.17}, {0.08, 0.45}}` is not your data ... it represents the pmf or distribution of the population data.

Comment: Great solution. When I try to work futher with the ProbabilityDistribution-function (´dist´), then I cannot use it with Probability[...]
I have an example with $X_1$ conditioned $X_1 \neq X_2$. How come?

Comment: Would need to see the exact example to be able to comment on that ...

Comment: How would you calculate: $P(X_1=0|X_1 \neq X_2)$ and $P(X_1=1|X_1 \neq X_2)$.
If it is any help. the results are 0.68 and 0.32

Comment: You could continue:  `Probability[x == 0 \[Conditioned] x != y, {x, y} \[Distributed] dist]`  ... and ... `Probability[x == 1 \[Conditioned] x != y, {x, y} \[Distributed] dist]` .. works fine

Comment: When I compute as `x==0`I get 0 as a result. However with `x==1`I get the correct result...

Comment: Checked it in v8 and v9 ->> works fine on both on my Mac. Suggest check your input carefully ... or quit kernel and start from fresh :)